# PHPUnit code coverage not working with configuration

Tags: php, unit-testing, code-coverage, phpunit

I have my PHPUnit setup and coverage report working fine without a white list filter. Once I add one however, the report seems to only partially generate as if PHPUnit quit unexpectedly. I do not get any errors or warnings.

My configuratoon looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php"
         colors="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="...">
            <testsuite name="...">
                <directory>./path/to/suite</directory>
            </testsuite>
            <testsuite name="...">
                <directory>./path/to/suite2</directory>
            </testsuite>
            <testsuite name="...">
                <directory>./path/to/suite3</directory>
            </testsuite>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../path/to/files</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="log/" charset="UTF-8" yui="true" />
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

Any idea on what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there was some script halting procedural code in the files I was white listing.

Comment: yes,  a hard `DIE()` or `EXIT;` in php code will stop PHPunit coverage reports.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for digging up an old one but I googled for phpunit code coverage not working and this one showed up.

I let code coverage just run it's course (think xdebug is used for it) and it was fine for a while.

Then when I created a new test it suddenly stopped working, code that ran was marked as not covered.

The test classes I created with phpunit: phpunit-skelgen --test

That one creates coverage annotations like: @covers MyClass::someMethod

Removing them solved it for me, xdebug now was used again and suddenly had 100% coverage.

One remark on coverage; Just calling a method once covers it in the report but mostly cannot be considered as covered. Calling it with null values and invalid values covers it.